# Eth_sign, blind singing and MM signing

Tags: security, signature

Having some confusion on what is what here.

1. Is there difference in enabling eth_sign in metamask with blind signing on ledger?
2. Many web3 sites today require user to sign message as log in method. I am not sure how secure that is and what kind of singing is going on there? Hash is often unreadable and we dont know what is in it.